# REPLACE within a CASE statement

Tags: sql-server

We have our team entering a dummy domain in some situations in our Email field, to signify that the entry belongs to a login ID list from another business unit (which uses a "gamertag" OR email as it's login ID). Something like this:

Retail Reps table a:

| email |
| --- |
| john123@dummydomain.com |
| jeff456@actualemail.com |

Users Table (provided from other business unit) b

| userID |
| --- |
| john123 |
| jeff456@actualemail.com |

We want to count the number of matches. Here's the CASE statement I wrote:

```
CASE WHEN REPLACE(a.email, '@dummydomain.com','') = b.userid THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS [Email LoginID match]
```

John results in 0 (no match) and Jeff results in 1 (match), even though both are a match.

Any guidance greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure both email and userID for John don't have non-display characters or spaces in them like at the beginning or end?  try wrapping both sides in a `trim()` and see what happens.  or doing a length on both tables values and see if the length is the same for John.  Also note: joining on a function like this will hurt performance.  if that's a concern consider adding a  computed column for your email table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to work:

```
SELECT u.UserID, count(*) as [Email LoginID match]
FROM Users u 
INNER JOIN RetailReps rr on u.UserID = Replace(rr.email,'@dummydomain.com','')
GROUP BY u.UserID
```

> https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=1569a6474024e04052ddcb4c4b14d23b

fwiw, you should probably be using a variant of [`example.com` or `dummydomain.test`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2606.html) as your dummy domain.

Comment: We're actually using a company specific dummy domain, but thanks for the heads up. Good to know for the future.

and my join was the issue! I wasn't removing @dummydomain from the join, so from the getgo it wasn't getting a match. Cheers mate!

Answer (score 0):

Well, I cannot see how you do the join between the tables, by this works for me:

> ```
> create table e (email varchar(255))
> insert into e values ('john123@dummydomain.com')
> insert into e values ('jeff456@actualemail.com')
>
> create table u (user_id varchar(255))
> insert into u values ('john123')
> insert into u values ('jeff456@actualemail.com')
> GO
> ```

4 rows affected

> 

> ```
> select 
> *,
> iif(user_id is null, 0, 1) as [Email LoginID match]
> from e left join u
> on left(e.email, charindex('@', e.email) - 1) = u.user_id
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> email                   | user_id | Email LoginID match
> :---------------------- | :------ | ------------------:
> john123@dummydomain.com | john123 |                   1
> jeff456@actualemail.com | null    |                   0
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=560b31fa29d918073e5a17f03ecac7a3)*

Comment: He wants both john and jeff to match. Why only one here? Also, if there were another `jeff456@differentactualmaildomain.com`, he would **not** want those to match.

Comment: oh crap! It's the join that's the issue! I'm joining on UserId = Email *facepalm* obviously nothing is returned for John123 because those are completely different values when the join happens.